# Get specific string content inside big string

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a big string like this:

```
[/az_column_text][/vc_column_inner][vc_column_inner width="3/4"]
  [az_latest_posts post_layout="listed-layout" post_columns_count="2clm" post_categories="assemblea-soci-2015"]
  [/vc_column_inner][/vc_row_inner][/vc_column]
```

What I need to extract:

```
assemblea-soci-2015
```

Of course this value can change, and also the big string can change too. I need a regex or something else to extract this value (it will be always from `post_categories="my-value-to-extract"`) from this big string.

I think to take `post_categories="` as the beginning of a possible substring and the next char `"` as the end of my portion, but no idea how to do this.

Is there an elegant way to do this also for future values with, of course, different length?

Comment: Just replace `as the beginning of a possible substring and the next char` in this `post_categories=" as the beginning of a possible substring and the next char "` with `(.*?)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<=post_categories=")[^"]+(?=")
```

`?<=` (lookbehind) looks for `post_categories="` before the desired match, and `(?=)` (lookahead) looks for `"` after the desired match.

`[^"]` gets the match (which is assumed not to contain any `"`)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aS9hR0/4)

Example PHP code:

```
$text='[/az_column_text][/vc_column_inner][vc_column_inner width="3/4"]
  [az_latest_posts post_layout="listed-layout" post_columns_count="2clm" post_categories="assemblea-soci-2015"]
  [/vc_column_inner][/vc_row_inner][/vc_column]';
preg_match ("/(?<=post_categories=\")[^\"]+(?=\")/", $text,$matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Output:

```
assemblea-soci-2015
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex in PHP:

```
post_categories="\K[^"]+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aS9hR0/3)

Answer (score 0):

This should extract what you want.

```
preg_match ("/post_categories=\"(.*)\"\[\]/", $text_you_want_to_use)
```

Comment: This returns me empty output